# "Text-align: center;" makes my right button go off the page

Tags: css, text-align

I've been furiously googling my issue and I can't seem to resolve the problem.

I have created and iFrame that scrolls through 8 images with a left and right direction button. When I `text-align: center;` the `DIV` that holds the images, the right arrow (#leaf2) dissapears.

Here is my HTML,

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="leaf1"><button onClick="image_onclick('prev');"><img src="images/leaf.gif/></button</div>
<div id="image_box"></div>
<div id="leaf2"><button onClick="image_onclick('next');"><img src="images/leaf2.gif"/></button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS,

```
body, p, image{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

button{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
}

#image_box{
    text-align: center;
}

#image_box img{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#leaf1{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 155px 0 0 8px;
}

#leaf2{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 160px 0 0 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was an error in copying but you have 
</button</div>
instead of
</button></div>

Also, if you're trying to center the images within your image_box, you'll need to set your left and right margins to auto. So:

```
            image_box img{
                margin: 0 auto; /* or margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; */
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

Comment: Also, if you're trying to center the elements within your image box, your horizontal margin will need to be auto, so

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntax issues here:

```
<img src="images/leaf.gif/></button</div>
```

Does the page render differently when you close the `src` attribute and the `<button>` element?

```
<img src="images/leaf.gif"/></button></div>
```

Also note that, according to the code you posted, you are applying `text-align: center` to an empty div.